# Cross-sheet scripting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible to update the row number on the first sheet from same cells in rest of workbook?

I have an index sheet (`Index`) with links to 53 other sheets for weeks, `Wk 1` thru `Wk 53`. I need to extract data from `Index:A2` to `Wk1:C19`, `Index:A3` to `Wk2:C19`, `Index:A4` to `Wk3:C19`, etc.

I have tried variations on `Index!$A(wk1!sheet())` to return the row reference without success.

The only thing that seems to work is to write the absolute reference in every `C19` on all 53 `Wk` sheets.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I know I’m not going to be your favourite chap for saying this, but the best way would be to consolidate your data. Having separate sheets for each week is going to cause you no end of headaches, whereas if you had all the data in one table, on one sheet and just added a week number column you could then easily pull the data for a given week onto a reporting layer. This would streamline your workbook, simplify your reporting and be far easier to change in future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INDIRECT()` to refer to a changing cell location, and CELL("filename") to get at the worksheet name so you know which week/row the cell needs to refer to.

```
=INDIRECT("Index!A"
    &RIGHT(
        CELL("filename")
        ,LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-2)
    +1)
```

Let's break this down:

1. Let's identify the worksheet you are on for each week. Go to cell C19 on your Wk1 tab. Enter `=CELL("filename")`. This step requires you to save your workbook first, otherwise there is no filename for Excel to recognise.

   You should get something like this:

   `C:\Users\yourname\Documents\[yourworkbook.xlsx]Wk1`
2. Now we need to strip most of that down so we only keep the relevant bit of information, ie the week number. Because the week number is always the last part of the string, we can use the `RIGHT()` function to grab it.

   If you just enter `=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),1)` you'll get week number 1, but this only works if you have fewer than 10 weeks. So we need to make the function flexible, and work out how many digits we want to keep. 1 or 2?

   We can use `LEN()` to identify the total number of characters in `CELL("filename")`. Then, we can identify the number of characters just in the worksheet name, by subtracting the length of the string up to the `]` from the total length, like this:

   `=LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))`

   This gives you a value of 3 or 4, but we don't want to include the two characters making up the "Wk" part of the worksheet name so let's subtract 2 so that we strip "Wk" off as well:

   `=LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-2`

   So, adding that to our `RIGHT()` function we have:

   `RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-2))`

   Last thing - on your Index sheet, week 1 starts on row 2, so let's add 1 to make sure we output the correct row number:

   `RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-2))+1`
3. `INDIRECT()` allows us to use a calculation in a cell reference. We add our row number to the static reference to "Index!A", concatenating the two using an `&`.

Putting everything together, that's:

```
=INDIRECT("Index!A"
    &RIGHT(
        CELL("filename")
        ,LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-2)
    +1)
```